# How to get and run TWAIN DSM files?

Tags: twain, image-scanner, merge-module

When I run the Twain implemented framework I get this error: `NO TWAIN DATASOURE IS NOT INSTALLED`. I am using Window7 64-bit. I downloaded some drivers from Sourceforge[TWAIN DSM FILES](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-dsm/files/TWAIN%20DSM%202%20Win/).

The download directory contains:

- TWAINDSM.dll
- TWAINDSM64.msm

I copied the `TWAINDSM.dll` file into `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. My doubt is how do I get the twain relevant `.ds` files.Iam don't know about dotnet relevant stuff. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download TWAIN sample data source [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/TWAIN%202%20Sample%20Data%20Source/).

The DSM and DS are different. The DSM looks for data sources.